# I am looking for the best way to check if a record is exist?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I would like to make a function that checks if data exists.
How should I code it?
I am using Spring boot.

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
private boolean isExit(String value)
{
return   jdbcTemplate.queryForList(“select count(*) * from TABLE where column = "+value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below method would work

```
  private boolean isExit(int value) {
        String query = "select count(*) from TABLE where column = ?";
        try {
            long count = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[]{value}, Long.class);
            return !(count == 0)
          } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            return false;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I hate to say that but it does not seem work correctly. Because  it will be always true  even when  record does not exist .

Comment: Are you getting any error? because I am using it my project & it works fine

Comment: I checked . long count = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[]{value}, Long.class);   even when count is0 . EmptyResultException didn't catcht it.